# compare that given String start With another String

Tags: java, string

What is the best way to compare that given String start With another String

Example :

```
  if("ABCD1234".startsWith("ABCD")){
        System.out.println("This is true ");
    }

    if("ABCD1234".substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("ABCD")){
        System.out.println("This also true ");
    }
```

Or are there any other solutions ?

Comment: *What is the best way...* Define "good".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) is the best option since it makes your intention clear to anyone reading your code.  If you want it to be case-insensitive convert both values to the same case before calling the method.

```
String prefix = "ABCD";
prefix = prefix.toLowerCase();

if("ABCD1234".toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) {
    System.out.println("This is true ");
}
```

If you want to be extra careful you may want to pass a `Locale` to `toLowerCase()` or at least be sure to call it on both Strings to ensure your code [passes the Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be:

```
if (s.indexOf("ABCD") == 0) {
  ...
}
```

However, I would prefer your first choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `equalsIgnoreCase` could be better in case of case insensitive equals but before substring you should check length and it will also create a new String in memory String pool.

Another way like it

```
    if("ABCD1234".substring(0,4).compareTo("ABCD")==0){
        System.out.println("This also true ");
    }
    if("ABCD1234".substring(0,4).compareToIgnoreCase("ABCD")==0){
        System.out.println("This also true ");
    }
```

But I think `startsWith` is better option here but make sure case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

also possible:

```
"ABCD1234".matches("ABCD.*");
```

Many other crazy solutions in my head :) IMHO the "best" way is to use your first suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the StringUtils from Apache Commons:

```
StringUtils.startsWith("abcdef", "abc") = true
StringUtils.startsWith("ABCDEF", "abc") = false
StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase("ABCDEF", "abc") = true
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: Why would you use a 3rd party library for the functionality that is already available in pre-defined one?

Comment: You are right with respect to the first method because `"ABCD1234".startsWith("ABCD")` is much clearer. But if you have to ignore the case I would prefer using `StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase("ABCDEF", "abc")` beacuse the intention is much clearer and it reads much better than for example `"ABCD1234".substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("ABCD")`. You are right, adding the dependency just for one line of code might be exaggerated. But my experience is that when you have to deal with strings in one place of your system you probably will deal with it in other places as well.

Comment: @Felix.. Agreed with the last line, and hence with the 2nd last line too. :)

Answer (score 1):

to be honest, first you should ask yourself is "abcd" equals "ABCD"?

if not, then i think first solution is much better, it is more cleaner and readable

if your answear is yes, then obviously, you cant use first solution

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer 2nd choice:

```
if("ABCD1234".substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("ABCD")){
        System.out.println("This also true ");
```

In this, u can additionally check by conbverting your string to LowerCase.

```
if(string.toLowerCase().startswith(string2))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have to write a Java app for work I use the [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) approach.

Comment: The language is stated: java.

Comment: The question is tagged `Java`.

Comment: Sorry didn't have my coffee. But yes I would still use startsWith!